# How to define a Control properties in a List

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have

```
List<Canvas> cv = new List<Canvas>();
List<Button> btn = new List<Button>();
```

But I cannot do this:

```
cv.Add(btn);
```

How do I add list of Button to a list of Canvas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you realize how little sense your question makes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a list of buttons to a list of canvases, since a list of buttons is not a canvas.

Had that been possible, what would happen if you then write

```
cv.Last().DrawCircle(...)
```

You just called a `DrawCircle` method on a `List<Button>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Button control to the [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) collection of the [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) control like the following:

```
// Canvas myCanvas
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.Content = "Press me";
myCanvas.Children.Add(myButton);
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311131/add-wpf-control-at-runtime) question to know how to add a Control in runtime.

Good luck!