# How to use a copy (or same) object in multiple threads

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, copy, clone

I am trying to make a warning window in an application. The window needs to run on a seperate thread and contains among other things a Canvas depicting a failing object. The Canvas already exists in the main application, and what i need is simply to show the same Canvas in the warning window. The problem is that i get an error saying that another thread owns the object.
I tried doing a deep copy using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) method but with no luck. Is there anything i missed, or is there really no simple method to copy a Canvas, or a collection of images. Alternatively, would it be possible to do the deep copy and then change the treading affinity of the copied object?

I should think that someone has encountered this problem before, but my serching skills have given me no relevant results this time.

Thanks in advance!
-ruNury

EDIT 1

```
    private Canvas cloneCanvas()
    {
        Canvas testcanv = new Canvas();

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
        {
            var t = SomeViewModel.GetCanvasWithImages();
            testcanv = CopyCanvas(t);
        }));

        return testcanv;
    }

    public static UIElement DeepCopy(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(element);

            var xamlString = new StringReader(xaml);

            var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(xamlString);

            var deepCopyObject = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlTextReader);

            return deepCopyObject;
        }

        return null;

    }

    private Canvas CopyCanvas(Canvas inputCanvas)
    {

        if (inputCanvas != null)
        {
            var outputCanvas = new Canvas();

            foreach (UIElement child in inputCanvas.Children)
            {
                outputCanvas.Children.Add(DeepCopy(child));
            }

            return outputCanvas;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Only the thread that created a UI object (main) can access the UI object.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason why I need a COPY of the object which can be shown on the NEW thread...

Comment: I feel your pain.  I have tried to do this and gave up. It seems that even a copy of a UI object still a UI object.  I know this seems extreme but you may needs to serialize to string and create the canvas.  I even had to serialize a FlowDocument to string to pass it from background to the main.

Comment: The annoying part is that I can put a break point in the dispatcher and see that testcanv contains the right data, but as soon as the im outside the dispatcher, testcanv children are owned by another thread...

Comment: Internally .NET only checks for ownership periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You can singleton pattern to maintain one object of warning window.

When you want to put the canvas into warning window, you have to use [Dispatcher](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher).

Dispatcher will marshal method call onto UI thread.

something like

```
  warningWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(
      System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
      new Action(
        delegate()
        {
          myCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        }
    ));
```

Where warningWindow will be available through singleton instance

Comment: I updated the question (should have included the code from the beginning). What I did is more or less what u suggest, but testcanv is not accessible at the return point.

Comment: testcanv = CopyCanvas(t); --> it looks like the culprit.

Comment: Instead of testCanvas= CopyCanvas(t), can you put testCanvas into a Grid in XAML (say grid1), and assign it like grid1.Children.Add(testCanvas);
                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311131/add-wpf-control-at-runtime

Comment: What will it help to put testcanv into a grid, when it is still not accessible in the warning window thread? As I see it the real problem is to have testcanv contain copies of the children in the 't' canvas...