# Add Usercontrol To A Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, user-controls

I have seen may examples one of them been
[Add WPF control at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311131/add-wpf-control-at-runtime)
Seem this solution has work for a lot of people. What the hell am I doing wrong? My Label won't Show on the canvas.

```
Label l = new Label();
l.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.Black, 0);
canBackArea.Children.Add(l);
l.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
l.Content = "Hello";
Canvas.SetLeft(l,20); 
Canvas.SetTop(l, 20);
Canvas.SetZIndex(l, lableList.Count);
```

Canvas Has a white color, Thus the Background.
canBackArea is a Canvas

XML CODE

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Canvas Name="canBackArea"
                Width="500"
                Height="300"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Background="White"
                MouseMove="canBackArea_MouseMove">
            <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                <telerik:RadContextMenu Name="mnuBack"
                                        ItemClick="ContextMenu_ItemClick"
                                        Opened="mnuBack_Opened">
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Name="mBackground" Header="Set Background Image" />
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Name="mSize" Header="Set Size" />
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Name="mLable" Header="Add Text" />
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Name="mChangeText" Header="Change Text" />
                </telerik:RadContextMenu>
            </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            <Image Name="imgBackground" />
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

After Add a lot of labels.

[image]

Comment: `lableList` what is that List<Label> ? and why do you want to set zIndex ?

Comment: I was thought the lable got lost behind another control. But thats not the case...

Comment: I have a suggestion for you please install and inspect your wpf element from running application using http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ - The WPF spy utility.

Answer (score 1):

This is my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Canvas x:Name="canBackArea">

</Canvas>
```

and this is my codebehind.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label l = new Label();

        canBackArea.Children.Add(l);
        l.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        l.Content = "Hello";
        Canvas.SetLeft(l, 20);
        Canvas.SetTop(l, 20);
    }
```

This works perfectly fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1mHi.png

It could depend on the context your using it in?

Comment: I added my XML can u take a look!

Comment: ScrollViewer is in other grid and that is in Usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue and I suspect the possible issues should be that

- No Foreground color is set to Label controls.
- zIndex should be more than any other children controls I think as Canvas.SetZIndex(l, canBackArea.Children.Count);

Below is what I have tried and tested.

### XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="269*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="New Label Content" Height="30" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtLabelContent" Width="200" Height="30"></TextBox>
            <Button Margin="10 0 0 0" Height="30" Width="70" Click="Button_Click">Add Label</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" x:Name="canBackArea" Background="White" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Window code-behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.Black, 0);
            l.Foreground = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.White, Colors.White, 0);
            canBackArea.Children.Add(l);
            l.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            l.Content = txtLabelContent.Text;
            Canvas.SetLeft(l, 20);
            Canvas.SetTop(l, 20);
            Canvas.SetZIndex(l, canBackArea.Children.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using your xaml and this

```
private void mnuBack_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Label l = new Label();

        canBackArea.Children.Add(l);
        l.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        l.Content = "Hello";
        Canvas.SetLeft(l, 20);
        Canvas.SetTop(l, 20);
        Canvas.SetZIndex(l, lableList.Count);
        lableList.Add(l);
    }
```

I can add labels

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was i was using styles and it is some how over writing my lable, i replaced it with textbox and every thing seems fine....