# Creating button and placing it on certain xaml window without using xaml code

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a button, set up his margins, height, width in my Window.xaml.cs file:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
b.Content= "Button";
b.Height = 50;
b.Width = 50;
```

**I want it to show up on my Window.xaml window when i start the program.** 
Using only these few properties is not showing it.

I could go in Window.xaml file and type in grid or wherever:

```
<Button Margin="10,10,10,10" Content="Button" Height="50" Width="50"></Button>
```

And it would show this button in the widnow, but using only these properites (in .cs code), is not enough

Comment: Although this question is probably easy to answer, it so hard to know where your understanding is at, that i am not sure any answer would help. Also there is a great need of more information on your part

Comment: i will try to edit it

Comment: edited @TheGeneral

Comment: You have to add it to a container. How you do it depends on the container, eg. myWindow.AddChild(myButton) or myGrid.Children.Add(myButton). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311131/add-wpf-control-at-runtime and https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/xaml/basic-xaml/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you only instantiated the button. The button doesn't know where it should be on the screen. It must be assigned to a named parent control like a grid or stackpanel.

XAML:

```
<Window>
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
RootGrid.Children.Add(b);
```